# Webcomics about a group of students in the future

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I'm trying to find a webcomic about a group of students in the future.  In one storyline they were in an architecture class and had to do a tour of their city.  There was one character that was part of a subculture that avoided genetically modified food.  It was on a hosting site, not its own website.